# JFace TreeViewers and the Eclipse e4 Framework / SelectionService

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface, e4

I'm having some difficulty with JFace TreeViewers and they way they interact with the e4 selection service / framework.

I'd like to understand what the intended way to manage the selection is (via the selection service) when using one or more JFace viewers in the same MPart.

Basic operation of two controls (a treeviewer and a tableviewer) works as expected, **however when focus moves to a different control within the part, and then returns to the TreeViewer via a right-click on a previously selected tree item, a selection event is not re-issued by the tree control, resulting in the e4 ESelectionService not being updated with the correct selection**, which has all sorts of trickle down effects such as handler's @CanExecute methods failing to function as expected.  Note that when focus returns to the TreeViewer via a left-click on a previously selected item... the selection event is issued as expected.

I'm sure i can code my way around this with MouseListeners or FocusListeners, but i want to do things correctly, and that seems a bit Kludgy.

To sum up:

- Is the TreeViewer behaving as expected?  (TableViewer doesn't appear to exhibit this behavior)
- What's the preferred work around?

Image with test case results summarizing issue:
[Test Case Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeE30.png)

Stripped down Sample/Test code is available here based on e4 wizard in eclipse.
https://github.com/krislyon/e4selection-issue

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A simple test on macOS seems to work OK but `TreeViewer` code depends a lot on the native control used for the tree so it may vary by platform.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look on MacOS, sadly...  I’m on Windows as is my target platform.  I’m sure someone has encountered this before, it doesn’t seem like a particularly rare thing to do...